# How to use SSL on local non-internet webpages?

Tags: networking, ssl, certificate

For local websites such as localhost which are not connected to the internet I want to use SSL. And as it is not possible to create letsencrypt for sites not connected to the internet, I had to use a self-signed certificate.
But most browsers inhibit the use of self-signed certificates. For sites connected with the internet I can understand, but it inhibits it even for local sites.

Is there a way to :

- make a certificate for a localhost or any other local non-internet website with e.g. Letsencrypt ?
  OR
- let the browser allow such a local non-internet site with a self-signed certificate ?

---

This is what is displays:
The owner is specified just below that line.

Website: localhost
Owner: This website does not supply ownership information. (???)
Verified by: **Internet Widgits Pty Ltd View Certificate**

Privacy & History

Have | visited this website prior to today? Yes, 3,835 times
Is this website storing information on my computer? Yes, cookies and 195 KB of site data Clear Cookies and Site Data
Have | saved any passwords for this website? Yes View Saved Passwords

Technical Details
Connection Encrypted (TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, 256 bit keys, TLS 1.3)
The page you are viewing was encrypted before being transmitted over the Internet.

Encryption makes it difficult for unauthorized people to view information traveling between computers. It is therefore unlikely that anyone read this page as it traveled across the network.

Comment: You may want to add your browser.  In general terms it is possible to create your own CA, add it to your root cert store, then sign your certs with it  (there is software to create your own CA - often wrappers around openssl).  That is likely overkill.  Googling a bit - have you tried https://www.pico.net/kb/how-do-you-get-chrome-to-accept-a-self-signed-certificate/

Comment: Does not work in Firefox. Despite instructions given:
https://www.opkey.com/blog/How-to-install-Self-Signed-SSL-Certificate-on-Mozilla-Firefox/ and after restart of Firefox, it still does not recognize its certificate. I imported the certificate after exporting it from the 'Certificate info' from the invalid certificate popup as your link instructed.

Comment: “make a certificate for a localhost” - Just use OpenSSL